# Smooth horizontal scrolling for card container on drag and release

Tags: javascript, html

I have a container with multiple card elements that I want to horizontally scroll smoothly on drag and release. Here is my code(This page is for mobile users so I used `touch` listeners):

```js
const container = document.getElementById('scrollContainer');
const cards = container.querySelectorAll('.card');
const itemWidth = cards[0].clientWidth;

let scrollDir = 0;
let startX;

container.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  startX = e.touches[0].clientX;
});

container.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
  scrollDir = e.touches[0].clientX > startX ? -1 : 1; 
});

container.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
  container.scrollLeft += scrollDir * itemWidth;
  scrollDir = 0; 
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 350px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00000016;
  padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="scrollContainer">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" data-index="0">
      card 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" data-index="1">
      card 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" data-index="2">
      card 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This somewhat works, but the scrolling is jumpy and I want it to smoothly scroll only one card width at a time on drag release.

Another scenario is this:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('scrollContainer');
const cards = container.querySelectorAll('.card');
const itemWidth = cards[0].clientWidth;

let scrollDir = 0;
let startX;

container.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
    startX = e.touches[0].clientX;
});

container.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
    // This line added.
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollDir = e.touches[0].clientX > startX ? -1 : 1;
});
container.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
    container.scrollLeft += scrollDir * cards.item(0).clientWidth
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 350px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00000016;
  padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="scrollContainer">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" data-index="0">
      card 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" data-index="1">
      card 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card" data-index="2">
      card 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This ensures that the container scrolls 1 item each time and the scrolling is not laggy, but it scrolls only when the touch ends.

How can I achieve smooth, controlled horizontal scrolling on drag release in vanilla JS?

Comment: It would be nice if I know the reason for the -1 point. Did I miss anything in the question?